# How to remap gg to g?

Tags: key-bindings

I don't use any `g combinations` except of `gg`, in normal mode. How can I make it so that pressing `g` once will be enough?

`nnoremap g gg` makes it wait for 3 seconds or so for a continuation of the command. Unmapping `g` beforehand doesn't work either, because I can't map to `gg` if I unmap `g`. Should I unmap every single combination that isn't `gg`?

Comment: Just because you don't use any `g` mappings now, does not mean you wont use any in the future. There are some rather handy ones in there. e.g. `gE`, `g_`, `gt`, `gT`, `g,`, `g;`, `gu`, `gU`, `gn`, and my personally favorite `gf`. See `:h g` for a list of all g mappings.

Comment: Oh yes, gf is awesome. But I don't need it that often right now. Maybe I'll move it to a separate hotkey when I'll need it. (Our names are so hilariously simular, I wonder if I looked at yours when I was choosing mine).

Comment: And I want vim and less to behave the same, if possible. Less uses a single `g`.

Comment: I probably use `gv` about every 90 seconds or so

Comment: There are also some plugins whose default mappings starts with g, such as `gc` in [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary). You should also consider that [you will](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/) run [out of keys](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/2bp9UdfZ63M%5B1-25%5D) if you continue using Vim for a long time, and that it takes some time/effort to train your muscle memory after you get used to a given mapping.

Comment: @mMontu I already did run out. I don't think it's such a bad thing, my vim is already 50 times more powerful than notepad, while being only 5 times more complex. I'm fine with that.

Comment: @PeretFinctor: But by using up keys, and thus blocking out the more powerful features of Vim, you stop yourself from being 50 times more powerful *tomorrow* than you are *today*. (And let's be honest, "fifty times more than Notepad" is still damn close to zero...)

Comment: @DevSolar If you care about me being powerful, can you recommend me a text editor whose source code I can understand? And one having a good enough scripting facilities to control cursor movement and everything else from script?

Comment: @PeretFinctor: Vim? Seriously, I don't know any better (and I have used *many* over the last three decades). However, I don't see why you need to "understand the source" to *use* an editor. Vim certainly has the scripting / macro facilites.

Comment: @DevSolar Well, don't you think it's dumb to have a source code, but never look inside? And never being able to change anything because you can't find anything ever? I'm afraid that vim is too complex for me to ever understand, maybe if I'll find something simplier...

Comment: @PeretFinctor: I have *megabytes* of source code that I use daily but would would not *dream* (in my worst nightmares) of looking into. I've been working as C++ maintenance coder for the last 15 years, and I just *know* how much work it is to effectively improve some source without actually being fully engaged in the project. *Especially* with a fully developed and track-proven code base like Vim. Vim might *look* like an "easy" or "lightweight" editor, and in some ways it might even *be* one... but it is also easily one of the most feature-rich editors available, i.e. complex.

Comment: @Yeah, just one look at the manual is enough to see that it's not at all simple. Hm, maybe I should look inside nano...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32509/discussion-between-devsolar-and-peret-finctor).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have a newer version of Vim (7.3.1261+) you can use `<nowait>`

```
nnoremap <nowait> g gg
```

Although, I can not stress the usefulness of some of the `g` mappings. Here is a short list of useful `g` mappings:

- `gE` - backwards end of word motion
- `g_` - to the last non-blank character of a line
- `gt` & `gT` - tab navigation
- `g,` & `g;` - back and forth through the change list
- `gu` & `gU` - case changing
- `gn` - visually select current pattern
- `gv` - reselect previous visual selection
- `gi` - start insert mode in the same position Insert mode was last stopped
- `gf` - go to file under cursor (My personal favorite)

See `:h g` for a list of all `g` mappings.

Personally I would just learn to use `gg` as it is a good habit and less is not known to be a good Vi/Vim emulator.

For more help see:

```
:h g
:h :map-nowait
```

Comment: `gi` is also pretty fantastic (enter insert mode where you previously left it). I use it all the time when I'm in the middle of typing a line of code and I have to go check something elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Yep. This is like people who map `w` to `:w<CR>` and `q` to `:qall<CR>` because it's "faster." You're just robbing yourself of the benefits of vim.

Comment: @WChargin oh, so I'm not the first one. Do you know more about this kind of remaps, can you redirect me to those people?

Comment: @PeretFinctor Not sure whether you're joking—my point is that these kinds of remaps are very bad ideas. People who do this are just trying to use vim as a run-of-the-mill editor; `w`, `q`, and `g` all offer extremely extensive functionality that you should be using frequently while editing, but which you are suppressing to shave off fractions of a second when you save. I don't know about you, but I save much less frequently than I move forward a word!

Comment: @WChargin I remapped macros related functions to a and A, and I use e and r to move a word back and a word forward.

Comment: @PeretFinctor: Why don't you use w / W and b / B for word-forward and word-backward, the way Vim provides out-of-the-box? -- You see the pattern here? You try to *wrestle* with Vim. Move *with* it, use the things it provides *as* they are provided. It *will* be easier that way, and more beneficial for your workflow in the long run.

Comment: @DevSolar Because e and r are right next to each other... I'm writing my own text editor, I'm learning vim just to see if I'm missing something good.

Comment: @PeretFinctor: Well, "**w**ord" and "**b**ack" are not bad either since they are mnemonic. And I wouldn't want to toss away "**e**nd" and "**r**eplace" just so that two (of three...) word skipping keys are next to each other. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Dunno, having two (four?) keys for moving a word forward is weird. I left only one. Now I have one command to move to the end of this or next word, and one to move to the beginning of this or previous word. If I want to select a word, I just <End><Select><Beginning><Copy>.

Comment: Err, I just istalled version 7.4.960 from git (sorry for delay), and here `nnoremap <nowait> g gg` doesn't execute gg instantaniously. it still waits. Can somebody else test it?

Comment: Ok, found what it was by `:verbose map g`, disabled with `let g:netrw_nogx=11111`. New trashy hotkey was defined after the processing of .vimrc was done, setting this variable to anything fixes this.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I still remapped g because it annoyed me how illogical `gg` is "go to document top" (two keystrokes) and `G` is "go to document bottom" (one keystroke). But I preserved some of the other functions in separate mappings (e.g. `nnoremap <Leader>u gu`, and all of my tab-remaps are of the form `nnoremap <Tab><key> <do tab stuff>`).

Answer (score 7):

Just to chime in, if you really really want a single key - you can still use ... *another* one (i.e. a key that you don't need that much)! In this way you can leave the useful `g` prefix alone.

For example, you can "overload" `0` to toggle between `0` and `^` functionality, when repeatedly pressed, and free `^` instead for your usage (since it's an intuitive *go up* character).

I'm sure this is not perfect, but here's a possible quick-n-dirty proof of concept:

```
function! ToStartOrNonBlankToggle(mode)
    if (a:mode == 'x')
        normal! gv
    endif
    let sp = col('.')
    normal! ^
    let ep = col('.')
    if (sp == ep)
        normal! 0
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> 0 :<c-u>call ToStartOrNonBlankToggle('n')<cr>
onoremap <silent> 0 :<c-u>call ToStartOrNonBlankToggle('o')<cr>
xnoremap <silent> 0 :<c-u>call ToStartOrNonBlankToggle('x')<cr>
noremap <silent> ^ gg
```

The above still allows using 0 as motion, and also from visual mode. On an indented line, `y0` would now copy from cursor position to the first non-blank character. If you want to copy to the start column instead, you'll have to go visual: `v00y`

You can now also use `13^` to go to line 13.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea, thank you!